# How to access an object in a class A from a class B

Tags: class, constructor, javafx

I have the following main class:

```
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Add to the list");
    TextArea peopleList = new TextArea();
    String name = "name";
    String surname = "surname";
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Person p = new Person(name, surname);
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, peopleList);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("People list");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I want that the constructor of the class `Person`adds name and surname into the `TextArea peopleList` into the main class.

```
    public class Person {
    public String name, surname;

    public Person(String n, String s){

    }
}
```

How can I access elements of the main class from other classes?

Comment: This just seems like a weird way to try to design your app. The `Person` class would typically just represent data - it shouldn't know anything about how the data is presented to the user. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: because my teacher is allways doing things in a tricky way in orde to see if we have well understood. Unfortunately, sometimes it results just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Make those variables either instance variables or class variables , Since local variable can be accessed only inside the function in which they are declared .

if you use instance variable make them private and Use getters and setters to access them

```
private TextArea peopleList = new TextArea();

public TextArea getPeopleList(){ // getter to access
         return peopleList;
 }
 public void setPeopleList(TextArea peopleList){
        this.peopleList=peopleList;
 }
```

Made the object of MainClass in other class and use them  using getters and setters.

Or Made them static/class variables in Main class so can be accesed with the name of Main Class.

```
static TextArea peopleList = new TextArea();
```

and in Other class

```
MainClass.peopleList
```

Comment: Ok but what if I have to create a GUI using a method like `setUpGUI(){TextArea peopleList = new TextArea();}` inside class A?

Comment: Don't initiate the variable untill you need it , Simple .
Declare as instance or static and initiate them whenever required

Comment: thanks. I asked because I saw it in my OOP proffessor. he uset to create a set up gui method and delcare objects as 'final'